# How to get path of different express route

Tags: node.js, express

Lets say I have the following routes in my express app:

```
router.get('/register', registrationController.register);

router.get('/confirm', registrationController.confirm);
```

In some service I would like to retrieve the absolute url of the confirm route.

Instead of doing something like this:

```
const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/confirm'
```

Is there an option to retrieve routes in some way like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const confirmRoute = router.confirm;

// Do something with the route name instead of typing it statically as a string
```

What can I do differently without installing another dependency?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're asking, but perhaps one of `req.path`, `req.baseUrl` or `req.originalUrl` would be useful.  See [express doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl) for what those are.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for your answer. I updated the question. In php frameworks its common to not statically type routes but rather to retrieve them like above. If the route path changes there will be in issue.

Comment: So, is `req.path` what you're looking for?  That will be what matched the router specification for the current route.  There is no such thing as `router.confirm` to indicate some other route's path.  You can define that yourself as in `const confirmRoute = "/confirm"` and just use that in both the router definition and some place else you want to access it.

Comment: Okay, the latter is what I am looking for, thank you! Could you give me a hint on how to access a ```const confirmRoute = "/confirm"``` in a different service than the router? I was thinking some global variable but I don't really know how to realize that. Do you have any tipps?

Comment: Not a global.  You need to export the value, either from your route module or put constants in a shared module that anyone who wants them can import. That's how you maintain proper modularity in nodejs.

Comment: Makes perfectly sense, appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a constant that you can use in multiple places.

```
const confirmRoute = "/confirm";
```

Then, you can use that in multiple places.  If those places are in separate files, then you can either export it from the file where it was declared and import in the other.  Or, you can create a shared constants file and export it from there and both other files that want to use it can import it from that shared file.

Alternately, you don't even have to expose the route itself.  You can keep that private to the file where they route is defined and then export and function that either retrieves the route path or just executes the redirect for you.